# Does firebase/FireStore collection.valueChanges cause a requery of the collection?

Tags: angular, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I am trying to make sure I do not do a bonehead move here, I assume valuechanges updates a stateful store on the client side with only the changes made from the server.

If I have a query that has *15* records, and I add a record, and I have a listener, does that listeter cause a full requery, thus billing me for said 15+1 reads or does valueChanges only query the one document that was added or updated and emit an updated state?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore doesn't do a full re-query when you have a listener attached to a query. The listener ValueChanges returns documents of 3 types.

1) ADDED

2) MODIFIED

3) REMOVED

Reference: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/listen#view_changes_between_snapshots